# NodeJS not showing variables

Tags: node.js

I'm starting with NodeJS with a this script:

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url);
    response.end('Hello bla bla bla');

}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) {
        return console.log('Algo ha pasado', err);
        }

    console.log('server is listening on ${port}');
    })
```

The output **should be**

> server is listening on 3000

but instead the output **is**

> server is listening on ${port}

The weird thing is that the same code in Mac actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace variables like you wanted you need to use back quote instead of simple quote

```
console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `${port}` syntax, you need to use string templates, so back ticks instead of single quotes:

```
console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
```

Or, optionally, you could leave it as a single quote and use string concatenation:

```
console.log('server is listening on ' + port);
```